# Redirect to another view using ajax call in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, form-submit

I have a registration form and on successful registration, it redirects to another view.
I use a submit button to insert **datas** to database, I want to clear the values in the current view and redirect the user to `logon page` in another view under same controller.
The submit type is not performing the action mentioned in jquery.Please help me

here is my code preview

**`Account/register`**

**`Account/logon`**

```
 Accountcontroller.cs
      [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel model, FormCollection form)
      {
           try {
                ---code
               }
           catch {
           }
      }

register.cshtml
     @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "accForm"      }))    
           {
             @html.textboxfor(.....)
             @html.textboxfor(.....)
             @html.textboxfor(.....)
             @html.textboxfor(.....)
                    ....
          <input type="submit" value="CreateAccount" class="buttonclass"               title="CreateAccount" ; onclick="SaveUser(this);" 

             }

    function SaveUser(btnClicked) {
           alert("clear");
           document.getElementById("regname").value = '';
           document.getElementById("regusername").value = '';
           document.getElementById("regemail").value = '';
           document.getElementById("regpassword").value = '';


           document.getElementById("regpassword2").value = '';

           $.ajax({
                   url: window.location.pathname + '/Account/Logon',

                   type: 'GET',
               })
               .success(function (result) {
                    alert("user saved successfully");
                     });
```

UPDATE:

```
   function SaveUser(btnClicked) {

       document.getElementById("regname").value = '';
       document.getElementById("regusername").value = '';
       document.getElementById("regemail").value = '';
       document.getElementById("regpassword").value = '';
       document.getElementById("regpassword2").value = '';
       alert('clear');
   $.ajax({


          type: "POST",
           url:  window.location.pathname + "Account/Register",

           success: function (response) {
               $.ajax({
                   url: window.location.pathname + '/Account/Logon',
                   type: 'GET',
               })
        .success(function (result) {
            alert("user saved successfully");

            // window.location ="";
        });
           },
           error: function (xhr, status, error) {
               alert("Failed");
           }
       });
}
```

I'm getting a Failed alert.
Please help

Comment: Are you getting any error

Comment: I'm not gettin redirected as submit button does insert the datas to the database.
but I'm not getting redirected to logon page after inserting the user

Comment: Just Replace the " url: window.location.pathname + '/Account/Logon' " into " url: '@Url.Action( "Register", "Account")' "

Comment: hi please check my EDITS on your update code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to Redirect Page on SuccessFull login then write the redirect code on Success (ajax success).
Exp:

```
$.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname + '/Account/Logon',
        type: 'GET',
         })
         .success(function (result) {
                    alert("user saved successfully");

         // window.location ="";
          });
```

Comment: Just Replace the " url: window.location.pathname + '/Account/Logon' " into " url: '@Url.Action( "Register", "Account")' "

Answer (score 0):

What Arun posted does totally work. But you have also to maintain the URL's in your client site code.

Another way would be to find out in your controller if the request which was posted is an AjaxRequest.
If so and some conditions apply you could redirect or even send a partial back to the client.

One way to find out if an request is an AjaxRequest with MVC 4 is

```
new HttpRequestWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request).IsAjaxRequest()
```

or parse the requests headers for the ajax properties.

This is also a SO question about detecting an Ajax Request
[Detecting IsAjaxRequest() with ASP.NET MVC and JQuery Form Plugin / File Upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681563/detecting-isajaxrequest-with-asp-net-mvc-and-jquery-form-plugin-file-upload)

OK if you look into posting ajaxy stuff in ASP.NET MVC with compiled routing...

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action( "Register", "Account")',
        data: {model:JSON.stringify(inputs)},
        type: 'POST',
```

or for form collections

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action( "Register", "Account")',
    data: {col :$("form_id").serialize()},
    type: 'POST',
```

...

use @URL.Action helper in your views.
Now when Register receives an ajax request handle the redirect  logic on the server ...

Comment: My problem is I don use ajax request in my controller.