# Replace usage of LINQ globally to invoke other class

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I'd like to inject some other code to replace all usage of LINQ in all code files in my project, without having to change the individual files. Like this:

```
var arr = items.Where(i => i.Price > 10).Select(i => i.Name).ToArray();
```

Instead of invoking LINQ-extensions here I want to redirect to this class instead: `Company.OtherLinqExtensions`, globally in one place.

I have lots of "using System.Linq" here and there. How do I redirect it to `Company.OtherLinqExtensions` without changing all `using` statements?

Comment: Can you provide an example of an expression that must be replaced? And how the method used from OtherLinqExtensions looks like?

Comment: I found this question also which describes what I'm after in a better way perhaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451099/how-to-override-an-existing-extension-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have some class in namespace `My.Company`, which uses LINQ as you described and has `using System.Linq` declaration. Then to "redirect" all calls to linq methods to your class, you just need to declare your class in the same My.Company namespace **or** in any parent namespace (like "My"):

```
namespace My.Company { // OR namespace My {
    public static class OtherLinqExtensions {
        public static IEnumerable<T> Select<T, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, TResult> selector) {
            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then, all extensions method will now call `OtherLinqExtensions` extensions (provided of course that your versions exactly match standard linq declarations).

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted!