# How to trap ILogger.LogCritical call and break in debugger?

Tags: c#, debugging, .net-core, nlog, ilogger

When someone writes a `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger.LogCritical()` call, there must be some serious things happened. I hope it will (log critical and) break while run in debugger. I've try the answer of [How to override an existing extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451099/how-to-override-an-existing-extension-method), it requires special namespace using. But I hope that everyone can use `LogCritical()` naturally, no need to double check whether it's calling original `LogCritical()` or my trapped one.

The only way I can think of is replace the backing logging library with mine, and it redirect calls to logging library with my breaking logic. But this implement restrict to specified library. If I want to change library in the future, I need to implement another one. And implement all the boring interfaces it needs, just for a few `LogCritical()` related breaking logic.

So, I wish to trap the general `ILogger.LogCritical()` call, not the underlying concrete one. Is this possible?

Comment: The .NET Core logging framework allows you to register many loggers, I suggest you create a new custom logger that does what you want and use it in-conjunction with your existing NLog logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you are looking for. But maybe something like this:

```
   var logFactory = NLog.Web.NLogBuilder.ConfigureNLog("nlog.config");
   #if DEBUG
   var debugBreakTarget = new NLog.Targets.MethodCallTarget("DebugBreak", (logEvent,parms) => System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break());
   var debugBreakRule = new NLog.Config.LoggingRule("*", NLog.Level.Fatal, debugBreakTarget);
   logFactory.Configuration.LoggingRules.Insert(0, debugBreakRule);
   logFactory.ReconfigExistingLoggers();
   #endif
   var logger = logFactory.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Showing NLog-specific-solution since you have added NLog-tag to your question.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/MethodCall-target

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wish a general trap on ILogger, not NLog specific one. But your `MethodCallTarget` is a new thing for me to learn. But after I try it (in NLog.config), if I use `async="true"`, the call stack doesn't include the `LogCritical()` one. (Although in log file I can found the last Fatal log, but break in debugger is much better. I can check every values related in debugger, not the log message only.) Only `async="false"` works. But this hurt performance a lot and can't be accepted by my current project.

Comment: @ChrisTorng When using NLog.config then you can have multiple <targets> sections. And you can just put the MethodCall-target in its own <targets>-section with async="false"

Comment: I should not try NLog.config one. It makes production environment check for every log request, makes all logs slower. I should use your `#if DEBUG` way, that only affects debug environment. Although your way only works in NLog library, not my original question that wish a general `ILogger.LogCritical` trap. But it does solve my current project's problem. So I'm marking your answer as accepted.